# Python 3 and Sybase and other databases

Tags: database, python-3.x, sybase

I am new to python. Sorry if this is a noob question. But I am still searching on how can I connect to databases using python 3. Most of what I can see on some sites, forums, are about python 2. Is there any good DBAPI or database driver for python 3 (especially sybase, oracle and sqlserver)?

Or did anyone succeed on porting sybase library using 2to3? I have no luck. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use Python (2.6,2.7 and 3.1 are supported) with Sybase ASE you need two things:

- `sybpydb` extension module for Python
- Sybase Open Client SDK

Sybase has [documentation for programmers wishing to connect to Sybase ASE with Python](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01692.1570100/doc/html/title.html).

If you are using Python with Sybase SQLAnywhere you need the `sqlanydb` module.

Here is the [documentation for using Sybase SQLAnywhere with Python](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbprogramming/pg-python.html).

Comment: Not sure.  It may work with 3.3, but it's not officially supported.

Comment: I am encountering this error "libsybdbcapi_r64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" on import sybpydb. I already added the lib to sys.path.