# Execute command in Sybase library for python

Tags: python, sybase

I am trying to use the sybase library to get a max result from a db table and store it in a variable

So i need something similar to:

```
import Sybase
conn = Sybase.connect('DB_SERVER', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', 'DB')
max_column = conn.execute('select MAX(column) from MYTABLE')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 3 and Sybase and other databases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902145/python-3-and-sybase-and-other-databases)

Comment: You may consider using pyDAL : https://github.com/web2py/pydal